# MacBook Pro mid 2009 Keeps shutting down when on Battery

Tags: macbook, battery, shutdown

Recently replaced battery and installed SSD's (Main and replaced cd with 2nd sad). Running ElCapitan. With the power cord attached it seems to be working fine. But on Battery it boots up and sometimes immediately shuts down or after a few min will randomly shut down. Right now the battery is at 75% and if I unplug it the system dies.

Comment: Seems obvious to me, the battery is dead.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like there is a problem with either both, or 1 of the following:

- Logic Board
- Battery

Diagnosing this issue is going to be a bit tough, due to the nature of "power issues," and not having access to an OS X server with MRI (Mac Resource Inspector) or AST (Apple Service Toolkit).

To start, and from what I have seen in a professional environment, the issue is 9/10 a problem with the battery. This issue is either the battery is not pushing enough power to the machine and causing it to randomly die (as yours is), or there is a short from battery cable, causing the battery to lose connection, even for a split second, to the logic board, thus causing your machine to turn off.

The best way to test the "shorting" issue, would be to inspect both the physical cable going from the battery to the logic board, as well as the connector on the logic board. See if you see any signs of wear or damage that could be causing a short.

If the battery looks good, and the connector looks good, the issue may be the physical battery and will have to be replaced. If, however, after replacing the battery again, you suffer the same problems, the issue sounds like the Logic Board Battery Connector, and thus would have to be replaced (the entire board)

As for the battery showing 75% and still dying, OS X has been known to not shown complete accurate battery percentage. This usually happens when changing batteries as you will have to "flush" the battery counter in order for it to detect a brand new battery and charge rate/level. To do this, you will perform an SMC Reset:

- Turn off your Macbook
- Unplug the AC adapter
- Remove the battery
- Press and hold power button for 5 seconds and then release the power button
- Reinsert the battery and connect the AC adapter

This should reset the internals of the battery and recalculate time and percentages. Once it has been reset, I suggest leaving your AC power connected and letting the battery fully charge. Then you can go about testing it to see if you are still running into issues.

Hopefully this helps a bit. As I said at the start, not having access to OS X Server with AST and MRI (I am assuming you don't) makes troubleshooting battery issues a bit tough. But,if after an SMC Reset and trying another battery, the problem persist, you can usually narrow the issue down to the Logic Board